# MySQL how to Update multiple rows with conditions in the same table

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update, mysql-workbench, dbvisualizer

I have a question, I want to update values in a table with conditions.
I have a list of users that I need to update their `accounting_id`, the key is `user_id`.
I want to do it in a single query.
The problem is that the query puts 0 in the `accounting id`. The DB is MySQL.

```
UPDATE users
SET users.accounting_id = CASE
        WHEN users.user_id = '102215' THEN users.accounting_id = '102'
        WHEN users.user_id = '102144' THEN users.accounting_id = '193'
    END    
WHERE users.user_id IN ('102215','102144');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's examine the expressions in the `then` part of your statement. e.g.: `users.accounting_id = '102'`. This is **not** an assignment, but a boolean expression, which evaluates to false, since `accounting_id` is not 102 (it's 102215 in this case).
The `=` before the `case` is used for the assignment. In the `then` branches you just need to return the **value** to be assigned:

```sql
UPDATE users
SET users.accounting_id = CASE
        WHEN users.user_id = '102215' THEN '102'
        WHEN users.user_id = '102144' THEN '193'
    END    
WHERE users.user_id IN ('102215','102144');
```

Comment: TNX you solved it